Image name stored is the temp path
I am tring to make a simple post that includes post title, body and image name. It is uploading the image and saving to the database. But the file name stored is the temp path.(.....\tmp\php6EFB.tmp)
I was tring to get it to save the file name.
The Post controller

$incomingFields = $request->validate([
           'title' => 'required',
           'body' => 'required',
          'image'=> ''

        ]);

        $incomingFields ['title'] =strip_tags($incomingFields['title']);
        $incomingFields ['body'] =strip_tags($incomingFields['body']);
        $incomingFields ['image'] =strip_tags($incomingFields['image']);
        $incomingFields ['user_id'] = auth()->id();
        
       
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();

        $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
       
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);

      


        POST::create($incomingFields);
        return redirect('/');


You are retrieving the filename but you are not updating your array, you will need to do this:
 $incomingFields['image'] = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();


And if you need the full saved path, you can do this:
$path = $request->file('image')->store('/path/to/folder/');


Thank you that makes sense. Would it be better to have another function in the controller to upload and the other to save?

Nope same function should be fine.
